# Retrieving rich text from RTEditText

Tags: android, richtext

I've integrated the Android-RTEditor (https://github.com/1gravity/Android-RTEditor) into my project and it seems to be working great as far as presenting my rich text, but I'm having a real difficulty extracting the rich text post-editing. I need to convert the rich text back into my native rich text format (for x-platform purposes) but all I seem to be able to get is the plain text.

I set the text as follows:

```
_textView.setRichTextEditing(true, true);
_textView.setText(toSpannable(string()), TextView.BufferType.NORMAL);
```

Then, when editing is done, retrieve it as so:

```
RTText text = _textView.getRichText(RTFormat.SPANNED);
Log.d(kClassTag, "text: " + text);
Spanned str = (Spanned)text.getText();
Log.d(kClassTag, "str: " + str);
```

But when I log that str it's just basic text:

```
02-17 13:50:01.619 3077-3077/com.xxx D/CKTextEdAndCont: text: com.onegravity.rteditor.api.format.RTEditable@100df7b
02-17 13:50:01.620 3077-3077/com.xx D/CKTextEdAndCont: str: Your words here...
```

So while I keep trying different approaches I was hoping someone might have experience to share (I'm looking at the converter code - specifically ConverterSpannedToHtml.java).

Comment: I didn't get you. You want the rich text with all the html formatting. right?

Comment: No, I want all the spans that have changed since the text was edited (bolding, alignment etc etc).

Comment: So further logging reveals that I *am* getting spans but they're regular Android spans not RT special spans - perhaps I can make it work with that...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RTFormat.HTML` instead of `RTFormat.SPANNED`

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that in my conversion to Rich Text I was using Android spans not RTEditor spans so of course I was not getting RTEditor spans back (though I assumed that RTEditor would upconvert regular spans to its own spans...)